# Evaluate the Limit of : $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^{2n}}{n^{\log_{2}n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to evaluate the limit of the following:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^{2n}}{n^{\log_{2}n}}$$
what I did so far is:
$$\dots \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n\ln{4}}{\log_{2}n\ln{n}}$$
every step from here like: using L'Hôpital's rule or keep simplify the expression did not success.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log the expression base 2. You will immediately see the leading term and conclude that it diverges.

Comment: Ok, I will get $2n$ now what about to log $n^{\log_{2}n}$? what I will get?

Comment: No, if you log the expression base 2 you get $n \log 2 - (\log n)^2$ which is $O(n)$, hence...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$2^{2n}=e^{2n\ln{2}}, \;\;
n^{\log_{2}n}=e^{\frac{\ln^2{n}}{\ln{2}}},$$thus
$$\frac{2^{2n}}{n^{\log_{2}n}}=e^{2n\ln{2}-\frac{\ln^2{n}}{\ln{2}}}.$$